# How to make the application on logout revert to the login screen in pyside

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyside

The application is a toy application for me to present the basics of MVC at a meetup. Basically, the application is (for now, composed of an app.py, controller.py, view.py, user.py) and flows as such:

(a) The app `app.py` initialises the controller

(b) The controller `controller.py` initialises the login view.

(c) The controller checks if the login view is in an Accepted State. If yes,
then it initialises the main view `view.py`.

(d) The main view has a button which upon clicked initialises the user view `user.py` where the user can type in some input, *m*. When the OK button is clicked and the user input, *m* is not empty, both the user view and the main view is closed.

(e) The user input, *m* is then printed out to the console.

My **questions** are these:

(a) How do I revert back to the login screen on exit?

(b) Is this implementation, "pure" MVC?

(c) The controller needs to be able to save all the modified variables(state) and commit them to the database before the application exits. For now, that is done in `cleanup()`. A scenario that I would want to implement would be , that  there would be a child widget attached to the main view where a user can change their login details. Upon such a change, the child widget window and the main view window should close and the changed login details be committed. Should I do that in `cleanup` or is there a better implementation?

(d) Is this the proper way to allow any other child widget of the main view to close the application? Also, I tried to using `sender()` to detect the button that closes the application but it returns 'Nonetype'. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# File: app.py
import sys, os
from controller import Controller
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *


if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        app = Controller()
        ret = app.start()
        app.cleanup()
        sys.exit(ret)
    except NameError:
        print("Name Error:", sys.exc_info()[1])
    except SystemExit:
        print("Closing Window..")
```

controller.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# File: controller.py
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from view import MainApplication

class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.model = None
        """
        if self.login != None:
            #self.__logger.debug("Login is cancelled")
            sys.exit(-1)
        """
        self.view = MainApplication()

    def cleanup(self):
        print(self.view.getSavedUserEdit())

    def start(self):
        return self.app.exec_()
```

view.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# File: view.py
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from user import UserPage

class MainApplication(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainApplication, self).__init__()
        self.__savedUserEdit = None
        self.__sender = None
        self.layout = QWidget()
        self.__initGUI()

    def __initGUI(self):    
        self.setWindowTitle('SSCE for StackOverflow')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 130, 140)
        self.__editBtn = QPushButton('Click me')
        self.__logoutBtn = QPushButton('Log Out')
        self.__editBtn.clicked.connect(self.__showEditPage)
        self.__logoutBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.__layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__layout.addWidget(self.__editBtn)
        self.__layout.addWidget(self.__logoutBtn)

        self.layout.setLayout(self.__layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def __showEditPage(self):
        dialog = UserPage()
        if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            self.__savedUserEdit = dialog.getUserInput()
            self.close()

    def getSavedUserEdit(self):
        return self.__savedUserEdit

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """
        self.__sender = self.sender()
        if self.__sender:
            answer = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Are you sure you want to quit ?',
                QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)
            if answer == QMessageBox.Yes:
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.ignore()
        else:
        """
        event.accept()
```

user.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# File: user.py
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class UserPage(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(UserPage, self).__init__()
        self.__userInput = ""
        self.__initGUI()

    def __initGUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('User Page')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 96, 86)
        self.__layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__sayHello = QLineEdit()
        self.__sayHelloLabel = QLabel('Type what you want: ')
        self.__okButton = QPushButton('OK')
        self.__okButton.clicked.connect(self.__logout)
        self.__layout.addWidget(self.__sayHelloLabel)
        self.__layout.addWidget(self.__sayHello)
        self.__layout.addWidget(self.__okButton)
        self.setLayout(self.__layout)

    def getUserInput(self):
        return self.__userInput

    def __logout(self):
        if str(self.__sayHello.text()):
            self.__userInput = str(self.__sayHello.text())
            self.accept()
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', "String is empty", 
                QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would use signals and slots.

Comment: @Trilarion Thanks. I guess I did not read it.